# Samba4 sysvol replication error

Tags: active-directory, samba4

**Production environment:** 4 DCs (windows server 2003) and near 150 workstations.

**Intention:** migration to Samba4

First, I've added 5th DC (CentOS 6.5, Samba 4.1.11-9.el6.x86_64 from SerNet repository).
It works, albeit with some flaws.

**Main concern:** sysvol replication.

I've googled already and discovered that this feature is not implemented yet.

**What I did:**

1. Mounted PDC share and manually copied sysvol contents;
2. Executed `samba-tool ntacl sysvolreset`.

And got:

```
open: error=2 (No such file or directory)
ERROR(runtime): uncaught exception - (-1073741823, 'Undetermined error')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/samba/netcmd/__init__.py", line 175, in _run
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/samba/netcmd/ntacl.py", line 218, in run
    lp, use_ntvfs=use_ntvfs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 1612, in     setsysvolacl
    set_gpos_acl(sysvol, dnsdomain, domainsid, domaindn, samdb, lp, use_ntvfs,     passdb=s4_passdb)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 1517, in     set_gpos_acl
    passdb=passdb)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 1480, in     set_dir_acl
    setntacl(lp, path, acl, domsid, use_ntvfs=use_ntvfs, skip_invalid_chown=True,     passdb=passdb, service=service)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/samba/ntacls.py", line 154, in setntacl
    smbd.set_nt_acl(file, security.SECINFO_OWNER | security.SECINFO_GROUP |     security.SECINFO_DACL | security.SECINFO_SACL, sd, service=service)
```

There are few similar situations described and resolved but the cause is surely different.

I'm not a programmer and (with due respect to programmers and their work) I can't grovel successfully through thousands of python lines to find out what's going wrong.

Found at least one solution based on rsync, but I need to replicate native windows AD, so this solution is not suitable for me.

Any suggestions?